# Does Ruby offer an equivalent of Perl's use strict?

Tags: ruby, perl

I mean, there is no `my` in Ruby. I found `use strict` in Perl to provide very good anti-typo protection.

Comment: No, I think it does not.

Comment: -1 for not using your favourite search engine.

Answer (score 15):

> The strict pragma does three things in Perl.  Two of the items are to
>   forbid the use of symbolic references and "barewords."  Ruby doesn't
>   support these features, so it's not an issue.
>
> The other feature of the strict pragma is to avoid creating random
>   global variables every time one is mentioned.  In Ruby, globals look
>   different from other variables (the leading $), so this is not really
>   a problem.  Local variables need to be assigned to before use, since
>   that's Ruby's method of declaration.  That solves the same problem
>   the strict pragma handles for Perl.

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ruby-talk-google/PiRnWplvGDw

Comment: There is probably one feature it does not forbid that is related to making a typo when updating an existing variable, eg. you define a var:
$counter = 0
 and later in code you make a typo when updating it:
$countre = -1

Comment: Good explanation here on why metaprogramming features make quite difficult to implement completely the use strict "vars" in ruby: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/115069